# How do I serve static files case-insensitively with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to serve static files with nginx, and I've already tried adding `~*` to the location option, but that doesn't seem to work with what I'm trying to do: serve files with case-insensitivity. Right now, I get a 404 if the case of the URL doesn't match the file's name in the file system.

For example, I have a file `/usr/share/nginx/psimages/scripts/ajaxprogress.js`, and I can access it by going to the `/scripts/ajaxprogress.js` URL, but I also need to access it by going to `/scripts/AjaxProgress.js`, which is currently giving me a 404 error when I try to load it.

Here's my config:

```
server {
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ngerror.log debug;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/psimages;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location ~* / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules

            # Wide-open CORS config for nginx
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        #
        # Om nom nom cookies
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
         }
         if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
         }
         if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Windows System is case insensitive, but I won't recommend you to use a Windows Server for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the authoritative [World Wide Web Consortium specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html) for URLs:

> URLs in general are case-sensitive (with the exception of machine names). There may be URLs, or parts of URLs, where case doesn't matter, but identifying these may not be easy. Users should always consider that URLs are case-sensitive.

The machine name is exempted because the [Domain Name System](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) had long prior defined names to be case-insensitive in §2.3.1.

Absent extremely compelling justification, you SHOULD NOT violate w3.org specifications as you never know what side effects it can generate.

As an example, using case-sensitive URLs can confuse caching proxies that may not distinguish between `ThisFile.html` and `thisfile.html` (or the 144 case variants of that name). Because, by definition, you ought never be able to know if you've hit a caching proxy, or how many of them, chances are high that this will yield the wrong document.

Comment: This answer doesn't even mention "nginx"; moreover, the discussion about the proxy is also wrong, since proxy WILL distinguish between `ThisFile.html` and `thisfile.html`, thereby causing more cache misses than would have happened otherwise (but yet the question was never about ignoring the cache in the proxy in the first place).  In all, this answer is good advice, but doesn't really fit the question at all!

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do that with stock nginx.

I think the idea is that you better know what the names of your files are.  Doing a case-insensitive file search would require reading and traversing the whole directory structure (e.g., with [`readdir(3)`](http://mdoc.su/o/readdir.3)), comparing each file entry with the input.  Imagine the directory had 1k files in it; this then results in doing a case-insensitive comparison against, on average, half of these 1k files, which would be hugely inefficient to do for a single request of what's meant to be a static file (repeat and multiply if directories themselves have to be case-insensitively searched as well).  Compare this with a single call to [`open(2)`](http://mdoc.su/o/open.2) when the file (with its correct case and path) is already known.

As such, it's likely deemed to be much more reasonable to ensure that the case of the static files matches, than to suffer such a dramatic performance drop (and the extra complexities involved in possibly having to have some sort of caches for the issue).  If, on the other hand, you don't care about performance for serving static content, you might as well proxy your static file requests to another server that does support/encourage such inefficient operation.

Comment: Case insensitive matching is not *that* inefficient. This does not result in more checks than usual; the only difference is that you lowercase each value before doing a comparison. (All it requires is to lowercase all the filenames (and the URL component) before doing the comparison for each component of the URL.) The main downside of this approach is, it's not platform independent, since Windows' filesystems will do this on your behalf at a lower level, while Linux filesystems will generally not; and porting a website from Windows to Linux would require a solution to this problem.

Comment: If you need regular non-technical users to be able to type in a url, you need it to be case insensitive. Knowing your own filenames does nothing to mitigate that need.

I think it is incorrect to say that there is no solution. I suspect that making the entire server's filesystem case insensitive would do the trick. But that's a pretty extreme cost. Hoping to find a better solution.